# Drop rows with NaNs based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have no problem with dropping ALL rows with any nulls, but I only want certain rows dropped with nulls and keep others

for example:

```
index  city      lo        hi
 0    Chicago    nan      75
 1    Boston     nan      nan
 2    New York   54       89
 3    Miami      nan      nan
 4    Seattle    49       nan
```

Keep in mind I have more rows than just 5. So, `df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')` would only leave me with `2    New York    54    89`

But what if I only wanted Chicago and Miami dropped? How would I set that condition on column 'city'? So I would end up with:

```
index   city     lo        hi
 1    Boston     nan      nan
 2    New York   54       89
 4    Seattle    49       nan
```

Comment: That makes no sense.  Boston also has `nan in `lo``, why wouldn't you drop it?  You literally want to specify a list of cities to drop out?  Or you want to use just `lo` or just `hi`?

Comment: also the values for `Seattle` have changed from input to output.

Comment: guys, it's just an example. I want to drop specific rows with any nulls because I don't need to fill those values. I want to leave only the nulls I will then fill later. Just clearing out the rows I know I don't need.

So yes, I want to drop any rows that have a null, specified by a condition in another column. So in the example, I don't want all rows with null dropped. Nor do I want all 'Chicago' or 'Miami' dropped that don't have a null.

so dropping by a city value would drop all with the city (don't want that)
dropping rows with nulls would drop all those rows (don't want that either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isin` to find all rows for your specific cities, then use `isnull` along the first axis and drop all rows from the original dataframe that have nulls in these rows.

```
cities = ['Miami', 'Boston']
idx = df[df.city.isin(['Boston', 'Miami'])].isnull().any(1).index    
df = df.loc[df.index.difference(idx)]

print(df)
   index      city    lo    hi
0      0   Chicago   NaN  75.0
2      2  New York  54.0  89.0
4      4   Seattle  49.0   NaN
```

`index.difference` will return all index values in `df.index` that is not in `idx`.

Comment: but that drops all 'Miami' rows, which I wouldn't want. how do I make that a condition? so drop rows with a specified city AND any null in that row...to dropna for only 'Miami' rows? Thus keeping any 'Miami' rows that don't have nulls

Comment: @chitown88 Finally got what you wanted. See my edit. Next time, please use an example that better represents what you want.